# Creating a subcollection with a randomly generated name (Firestore w/ React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am trying to make a firestore structure similar to the following:

collection (userID) --> document (courseID) --> subcollection (lectureID) --> Q&A arrays

where the userID, courseID, and lectureID are all randomly generated values by firestore.  Using authentication via firebase allows for the userID to be randomly generated, and the code below works well to create a course with a random courseID:

```
firestore.collection(authorId).add({

     (...)
```

However, I'm running into issues trying to create a subcollection with a random Id. At first I was trying to do something such as:

```
firestore.collection(authorID).doc(courseID).add({

     (...)
```

but the .add() apparently doesn't work for subcollections. Is there another function I can use that will allow me to create a subcollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add a document to a subcollection, you need to build a reference to it, using a name that you decide ahead of time, then add() the document using that reference.

```
firestore
    .collection(authorID)
    .doc(courseID)
    .collection("name-of-your-subcollection")
    .add({ ...})
```

I strongly suggest **not** using randomized names for subcollections, because you will have a very hard time finding and querying them later.

Comment: I understand.  For my specific application, the name of the subcollection isn't useful (since queries will be done via user selection of the lecture on a react-redux UI or randomly selected via random number generator for testing purposes).  I was hoping there would be a way to just have firestore generate a random name for the subcollections to avoid the possibility of having 2 subcollections with the same name.  

I'll figure out a reasonable naming convention and implement it into this project.  Thanks Doug Stevenson for your advice and clarification.

Comment: Even if you just want one subcollection, you will still need to give it a name that appears consistently throughout your app.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again Doug! :)